# get data in html text box

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am displaying data in tree structure using dojo.The data will be read from xml file.when we click the particular data in tree we are getting the name of that.
    newArgs.name = fileStore.getValue(item, "name");
What i want is ,when the particular node is clicked that name sholud be displayed in text box.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question properly, you could set the value of text box with (i'm assuming you've created the textbox with dojo as well)

```
dijit.byId('textboxName').attr("value", yourValue);
```